# Fill empty values in array with values from other array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have two rows in mysql and these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `fruits_colors` WHERE `name` = "default"
SELECT * FROM `fruits_colors` WHERE `name` = "example"
```

I'm getting:

```
//result from first query    
$default_row = array(
    'banana' => 'yellow',
    'apple' => 'red',
    'grape' => 'green',
    'blueberry' => 'blue'
    'raspberry' => 'red'
);

//result from second query 
$example_row = array(
    'banana' => 'yellow',
    'apple' => 'GREEN',
    'grape' => '',
    'blueberry' => 'blue'
    'raspberry' => ''
);
```

So, now I want to fill all empty values from $example_row with default values ($default_row), but not replace those not empty. So I should get:

```
$example_row = array(
    'banana' => 'yellow',
    'apple' => 'GREEN', // keep original from this array
    'grape' => 'green', // filled from $default_row
    'blueberry' => 'blue'
    'raspberry' => 'red'// filled from $default_row
);
```

I know that I can make foreach with $example_row, check every key and if value is empty then set with value from other array. But, is there any more elegant shorter way to do this?

1. Can I connect these array with some build-in PHP function?
2. Maybe can I do this directly in SQL query?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

try this solution.

```
$return = array();
foreach($example_row as $k => $v) {
    if(empty($v) || ($v == "")) {
        $return[$key] = $default_row[$key];
    } else {
        $return[$key] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($return);
```

Comment: if the value in $example_row is empty, set with value in $default_row.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(`name`,''), SELECT `name` FROM fruits_colors
 WHERE `name` = "default")
FROM fruits_colors
 WHERE `name` = "example"
```